# return all the columns in a MySQL table in a string format

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

Is there a way to return all the columns in a MySQL table in a string format?

I would like to have something like this returned:

`course_id, name, par, yds, mtrs` etc.

I am aware of how to show the fields/columns in a table (`SHOW FIELDS FROM course;`) however these are returned in a tabular format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select group_concat(column_name separator ', ') 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'course' 
group by table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

If your DB-user has access to the information schema, you can use the following:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `COLUMN_NAME` )
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'your_database_name'
AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'your_table_name'
GROUP BY `TABLE_NAME`
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,',') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'

Comment: That returns an error: `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,',') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE' at line 7`

Comment: Are you using an application or are you running it from the command line?

Comment: I'm using SQLYog v10.12 (latest version) and i'm seeing an error. I can't see what's wrong with the query though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13443/discussion-between-chim-and-crmpicco)