# i want to fetch data according to tables which are dynamic means their name might change in databse from time to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query, where I need to fetch data from tables which are dynamic in nature, meaning their name might change in the database from time to time.

So, first step is that from the schema, I will get to know what the recent table names are under that schema from which I have to fetch the data, but the second part is the difficult one for me: Once I've got the table name, how could I use those tables to fetch data inside them?

Comment: MySql is not Sql Server.

Comment: Seems to me you gonna have to query Information_Schema to pickup table and column names ... and then creation of statement should be easier once you know all info ... check out this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341192/return-all-the-columns-in-a-mysql-table-in-a-string-format

Comment: @Veljko89.. Using Information _schema I got the table names that was the first part I was talking about.SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'xyz'. But after that what should I do with those table names?

Comment: Yes, now you go for sys.columns where table = @YourTableName and then create basic insert statement

Comment: Actually I can't use Table names that I got in through Information_schema because once again those table names are changed and I have to edit my 500 line query all again, I want some dynamic solution in which I don't have to specify a table name anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL for that

```
use tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE dynamic_table
(
a INT,
b INT);
GO
INSERT INTO dynamic_table VALUES (1,1);
GO

DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(200) = 'dynamic_table';

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX),
    @columns VARCHAR(MAX);

  SELECT @columns = 
                 d FROM (
                 SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(
                         (
                             SELECT ',' + ds1.name AS [text()]
                             FROM sys.columns ds1
                             WHERE ds1.object_id = ds2.object_id

                             ORDER BY ds1.name FOR XML PATH('')
                         ), 2, 1000) AS d
         FROM sys.columns ds2 WHERE ds2.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
         ) a;
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @table_name;
EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE dynamic_table
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below one and change as per your requirement, Hope it's helpful.

```
Declare @Table varchar(100)
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
Set @Table = 'etl_run'
Set @Sql = 'Select * from ' + @Table
exec (@Sql)
```

Comment: declare table varchar(max)
declare sql nvarchar(max)
set table = 'select TABLE_NAME from Information_Schema.Tables where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'xyz''
set sql = 'Select distinct FAM_CODE, RUN_DATE from' + @table + 'group by FAM_CODE,RUN_DATE'
exec(sql). when in set table I am writing specific table name it's working perfectly but as soon as I put this query to fetch tables according to Specific Schema, in set table it started showing me error. First thing I am not able to put where condition and second thing it's showing syntax error near TABLE_NAME. Please help , I am new to this.

Comment: Hi Please insert all the table names in a temp table with row id's and then use a while loop and increase the row id value every time with one and run your script multiple times.

Comment: Let me know if you still have issue, i will create the script for you.